# Pycharm professional 2018.3.2 not loading ideavimrc

Tags: pycharm, ideavim

I recently started using Pycharm Professional 2018.3.2 and installed the IdeaVim plugin from Pycharm repository. However my Ideavimrc is not loading and taking any effect in the pycharm. I have tested this both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it didn't work on any OS.

On Ubuntu the location of ideavimrc is ~/.ideavimrc and on windows the location was c:/User/Myuser/_ideavimrc. On windows i tested by renaming the file to .ideavimrc as well.

I searched a lot on this and i could not find anything. Has anything changed in the recent versions ? I am attaching my ideavimrc for sample and also the Pycharm log file as for Windows 10.

[.Ideavimrc](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxJZv2lZ1YuJeEY5Y1FRTnpSSkQtU05iU0Ricl9sejFTV3Br)

[Pycharm log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1u_-bCrdcBsDWITEydNGQqy1FkR9lcA1Z)

Any clues what can i do ?

PS: I have opened a support case with Jetbrains as well but even they have not replied and been able to provide even a work around for this.

Comment: Please attach the contents of your ~/.ideavimrc. I was unable to open the links you've provided. Google Drive asks for permissions. It's likely there is an error there, since the location is correct, at least on Linux. It's in the user's home directory (~ points to it) and the name of the file is .ideavimrc

Comment: Just updated link permissions. Also the file name is .ideavimrc only and the location is in home directory on linux and on windows it is c:/Users/myuser/.ideavimrc. I tried with _ideavimrc as name on windows. By the way i posted the question with JetBrains support as well and even they did not gave me any answer.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh infact i tried removing the ideavim plugin and then reinstalling it again to see if that works but no success. Finally removed pycharm with all settings/caches/local directories also removed and then installed it again in a new directory but still i am having same issue. PyCharm simply fails to load my .ideavimrc. Its neither working on Ubuntu 16.04 nor on Windows 10.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh did you get chance to look at it ?

Comment: I'm the maintainer of IdeaVim and I work for JetBrains. I've sent my reply via our support channel. I hope we'll figure out the source of the problem soon.

Comment: @AndreyVlasovskikh is there any update on this? I see similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your .ideavimrc file has to be same encoding as your project files. Try to check this out.

In my case IdeaVim created .ideavimrc with windows-1251 encoding when my project files was with UTF-8. And config wasn't working. I changed encoding, reloaded Rider and it has finally applied.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Jetbrains support I was able to fix this, in my case the issue was that file was `tab` seperated.

I changed the file to be `space` seperated and that solved the issue for me.